# Is it proper to have element parameters that are related to parent element?

Tags: xml

I'm designing my own GUI and I use XML to it's storing. It has elements that have special properties for children, TabFolder has tab name for each child and Window has position for each child.

Example 1:

```
<tabfolder>
  <stuff tabtitle="Stuff">...</stuff>
  <stuff tabtitle="Stuff2">...</stuff>
</tabfolder>
<window>
  <button position="title_right" id="close"></button>
  <button position="title_right" id="hide"></button>
  <stuff position="content"></stuff>
</window>
```

Example 2:

```
<tabfolder>
  <tab>
    <title>Stuff</title>
    <content><stuff>...</stuff></content>
  </tab>
  <tab>
    <title>Stuff2</title>
    <content><stuff>...</stuff></content>
  </tab>
</tabfolder>
<window>
  <title_right>
    <button id="close"></button>
    <button id="hide"></button>
  </title_right>
  <content><stuff></stuff></content>
</window>
```

Which of these examples shows proper way to go?

1st much shorted.
2nd looks more standard.

Answer (score 0):

Child should have properties relative to it's parent.

Whether that's left = 3 inside Panel with a left of three inside window with a left of 26, giving you a screen position of 32

or Font pointing to one for the child or one for its parent.

Otherwise each parent has to "know" way too much about all the types of child control it might contain, leading to a very messy and extremely fragile design.

Certainly this is the way  most GUI component libraries work and deviating from that ,unless you are creating all your own components and not using the built ins, will get painful quick.

If you need the first format, extract it from the second, use it, then bin it.